# Websockets/react - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, node.js, error-handling, socket.io, cors

I am coding along the following : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwFA3YMfkoc&t=234s

At the 1 hour 16 min time stamp, i have come across an error when i try to enter the chat message:
i am getting this error on my front end console

GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OsKfDVD net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

my backend code(server.js)

```
const express = require("express"); // we are in the node not in react so we have to do imports like this using require
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const http = require("http"); // we need a node build in modules= which is http

const { addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUserInRoom } = require("./users.js");

const cors = require("cors"); // Import the cors middleware

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; // we can use 5000 only but during deployment we can have to defined a specific port which is inside process.env.port

const router = require("./router"); // importing the router here

const app = express(); // app that we inialised from express

const server = http.createServer(app); // we are passing the app that we initialised from the express

//const io = socketio(server); // we are creating an instance and passing the server inside the instance we created
// app.use(
//   cors()
// );

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);

const io = socketio(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // this socket is going to be connected as client side socket

  socket.on("join", ({ name, room }, callback) => {
    // we can use that callback in socket.on event
    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, name, room }); // we are getting data on the backend

    if (error) return callback(error); // if error we will simply return callback with error and this error is coming from addUser function error statement

    // now someone join so there is system messages when someone join the team
    socket.emit("message", {
      user: "admin",
      text: `${user.name} , Welcome to the room ${user.room}`,
    });

    // socket.broadcast will tell everyone in that room beside that user that it has join the room
    socket.broadcast
      .to(user.room)
      .emit("message", { user: "admin", text: `${user.name} has joined!!!` });

    // here we emmited message from the backend to the frontend using socket.emit()
    // now if there is no error then we use socket.join that simply that user has join the room
    socket.join(user.room);
    callback(); // but it will not run if there is no error
  });

  socket.on("sendMessage", (message, callBack) => {
    const user = getUser(socket.id); // we will get the user who sends the message from the frontend

    io.to(user.name).emit("message", { user: user.name, text: message }); // what we are getting from the frontend

    callBack(); // so that we can do something after the message is send
  }); // now we are waiting for the frontend to send message this callback will run after the event(sendMessage) is occur

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user has left!!!");
  });
});

app.use(router); // we can now call it as middleware

// starting the server now

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server has Started ${PORT}`);
});
```

and this is my frontend code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; //useEffect is basically for lifeCycle method inside the hook

import queryString from "query-string"; // this module help us in retrieving from the Url
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

export default function Chat() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(""); // to specify every single message
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); // keep track of all the messages
  const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
  const location = useLocation(); //we dont pass it as a prop now ..now we use useLocation() instead of passing it as a prop
  // this is coming from react router and we are recieving it as a prop
  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search); // it will give us the credentials that we input

    //when we get our first connection we gonna set that socket to io(END_POINT)
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    socket.emit("join", { name, room }, () => {
      // we can anythinh from the client side which backend can recoginize
    });
    return () => {
      // this will happen on unMounting on leaving the chat
      socket.disconnect(); // disconnect is the reserved keyowrd so we use this
      socket.off(); // it will off it per user
    };

    // console.log(name, room);
    // console.log(location.search); // it will only give us the parameter not the full url
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]); // Ensure useEffect runs when the value in this array changes only then it will rerender the useEffect otherwise not
  useEffect(() => {
    // this useEffect is for handling messages
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });
  }, [messages]); // only run this when messages array changes

  // function for sending messages
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (message) {
      socket.emit("sendMessage", message, () => setMessage("")); // after message is send it will clear the input field
    }
  };
  console.log(message, messages); // lets see the messages

  return (
    <div className="outerContainer">
      <div className="container">
        <input
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          onKeyPress={(e) => (e.key === "Enter" ? sendMessage(e) : null)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; //useEffect is basically for lifeCycle method inside the hook

import queryString from "query-string"; // this module help us in retrieving from the Url
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

export default function Chat() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(""); // to specify every single message
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); // keep track of all the messages
  const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
  const location = useLocation(); //we dont pass it as a prop now ..now we use useLocation() instead of passing it as a prop
  // this is coming from react router and we are recieving it as a prop
  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search); // it will give us the credentials that we input

    //when we get our first connection we gonna set that socket to io(END_POINT)
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    socket.emit("join", { name, room }, () => {
      // we can anythinh from the client side which backend can recoginize
    });
    return () => {
      // this will happen on unMounting on leaving the chat

      socket.disconnect(); // disconnect is the reserved keyowrd so we use this
      socket.off(); // it will off it per user
    };

    // console.log(name, room);
    // console.log(location.search); // it will only give us the parameter not the full url
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]); // Ensure useEffect runs when the value in this array changes only then it will rerender the useEffect otherwise not
  useEffect(() => {
    // this useEffect is for handling messages
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
      setMessages([...messages, message]);
    });
  }, [messages]); // only run this when messages array changes

  // function for sending messages
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (message) {
      socket.emit("sendMessage", message, () => setMessage("")); // after message is send it will clear the input field
    }
  };
  console.log(message, messages); // lets see the messages

  return (
    <div className="outerContainer">
      <div className="container">
        <input
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          onKeyPress={(e) => (e.key === "Enter" ? sendMessage(e) : null)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```